# How can I only display an add review form if a user hasn't already submited a review?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord, show-hide

Hi I'm a super beginner and working on my first app, I have a table of venues and users can add reviews to the venues. I would like to be able to hide the review form to users once they have submitted a review, to stop them from submitting more.

This is what I have now:

**add review form on venue show page**

```
<% if reviewed? %>
    <%= form_for [@venue, @review], :class => 'rating_ballot' do |f| %>
      <%= f.label("value_1", content_tag(:span, '1'), {:class=>"rating", :id=>"1"}) %>
      <%= radio_button_tag("review[rating]", 1, :class => 'rating_button') %>

      <%= f.label("value_2", content_tag(:span, '2'), {:class=>"rating", :id=>"2"}) %>
      <%= radio_button_tag("review[rating]", 2, :class => 'rating_button') %>

      <%= f.label("value_3", content_tag(:span, '3'), {:class=>"rating", :id=>"3"}) %>
      <%= radio_button_tag("review[rating]", 3, :class => 'rating_button') %>

      <%= f.label("value_4", content_tag(:span, '4'), {:class=>"rating", :id=>"4"}) %>
      <%= radio_button_tag("review[rating]", 4, :class => 'rating_button') %>

      <%= f.label("value_5", content_tag(:span, '5'), {:class=>"rating", :id=>"5"}) %>
      <%= radio_button_tag("review[rating]", 5, :class => 'rating_button') %> <br>

      <p>title: <br>
      <%= f.text_field :title %></p><br>

      <%= submit_tag %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

**application controller**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper :all # include all helpers, all the time
  protect_from_forgery # See ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection for details
  helper_method :reviewed?

  protected

  def reviewed?
    true
  end

   private

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
end
```

I cant figure out what the reviewed? helper should be to allow me to do this, any help is greatly appreciated!

**edit**

I've added the has_reviewed helper to the application controller, it now shows this error:

```
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id

Extracted source (around line #79):

76:     <%= render :partial => 'reviews/review', :collection => @venue.reviews %>
77:   </div>
78: 
79:   <% if reviewed? %>
```

**application controller**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper :all # include all helpers, all the time
  protect_from_forgery # See ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection for details
  helper_method :current_user
  helper_method :has_reviewed
  helper_method :reviewed?

  protected

  def reviewed?
    Review.has_reviewed(@current_user.id, venue.id)
  end

  def has_reviewed
    !Review.where(:user_id=>user,:venue_id=>venue).blank?
  end

   private

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
end
```

**another edit**

I've changed the reviewed? helper method to:

```
  def reviewed?
    if current_user
      Review.has_reviewed(@current_user.id, @venue.id)
    else
      nil
    end
  end
```

but it gives undefined method `has_reviewed' for # error

**schema**

A venue has many reviews

A user has many reviews

A review belongs to a user and a venue

the routes looks like this:

```
App::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :sessions
  resources :users
  resources :venues do
    resources :reviews
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you make the change as suggested by Wes, the `reviewed?` method would look in the database to see if this user has made a review.

The reviews table will need to have a column for the user that made the review and the venue it reviewed.

So the code would look something like this...

EDITED to reflect schema recently added

In the controller

```
def reviewed?
  if current_user
    @current_user.has_reviewed(@venue.id)
  else
    nil
  end
end
```

In the User model...

```
class User < ...
  has_many :reviews

  def has_reviewed(venueid)
    reviews.exists?(:venue_id => venueid)
  end

  ...
end
```

Basically I think the has_reviewed is better off in the User model as the user has_many reviews, and then it can check if the user has reviewed the given venue.
I am presuming that the Model Review has a foreign key to venue called venue_id, as a Review belongs_to a Venue and that would be the standard thing.

Comment: The `has_reviewed` method could be one line, like: `!Review.where(:user_id=>user,:venue_id=>venue).blank?`

Comment: Or even better.. `Review.exists?(['user_id = ? AND venue_id = ?', user.id, venue.id]`

Comment: @Jim Morris Thanks for the answer its has helped me understand much better. The reviewed? helper is giving me this error though "Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id" what could this be? Thanks again

Comment: @Dave That means either @current_user is nil or @venue is nil, remember you need to make sure both those are set before the helper is called. Also from the look of `def current_user` it will return nil if the user does not exist so you need to cover that case

Comment: Where did you put the has_reviewed? method? Can you add that to the question?

Comment: I edited my example, presuming if the user does not exist then they probably have not added a review. @venue will still need to be set in the controller somewhere before this is called.

Comment: @Jim Morris, thanks for having another look I've updated my question, I've put both helpers into the application controller

Comment: @Dave Ok I see the problem. The `has_reviewed` method needs to go in the Review model presuming you have one. It is not a helper. Typically you put things that access the database in the model. If you don;t have a Review model, then where are your reviews stored? Maybe you need to also post your schema.

Comment: @Jim Morris, ahh thanks very much I've moved it over now but getting a undefined method `has_reviewed' error. I've added the schema to my question

Comment: Ok given the schema I'd refactor a bit, I'll update my answer in a bit.

Comment: @Jim Morris, thats done it! thanks so very much it works great!

Comment: @Dave you are welcome, May I recommend one of the Rails books to make your transition easier? I like the ones from Pragmatic progs, they got me started.

Answer (score 1):

```
<% unless reviewed? %>
[...]
<% end %>
```